# Error al crear ZIP uilizando la clase ZipArchive de php

Tags: php, linux

He mudado mi sitio a una instancia EC2 con Linux 2 en Amazon donde corro un servidor apache con php 7.2. En mi script utilizo la clase ZipArchive de PHP para crear archivos zip pero el servidor me devuelve este error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found

Alguien sabe como puedo resolver este problema?. Gracias!

Comment: El paquete `php` de las instancias de Amazon Linux 2 tienen todo lo necesario para trabajar con archivos ZIP de serie, pero distribuye la versión de **PHP 5.4.16**, no la 7.2, por lo que es probable que hayas instalado por tu cuenta una versión superior. Deberás indicarnos qué pasos o qué guía has seguido para instalar PHP 7.2 en tu instancia de Amazon para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo general todos los no vienen incluidos solo los mas basicos para la ejecucion de php en este caso deberias intalarlo con los comandos:

```
apt-get install php7.2-zip
apt-get install php7.2-gd
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Bryro, intente lo que me dijiste pero me dice 'sudo: apt-get: command not found' , asique remplace apt-get por yum y me dice: 'No package php7.2-zip available.' y 'No package php7.2-gd available.' Gracias!

Comment: a ok entonces dale un `yum list  php7.*-zip` y la ultima version que te salga es la que debes intalar y remplazar `service apache2 restart` por `service  http  restart` y eso seria todo

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, hice 'yum list php7.*-zip' y me devuelve: Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
183 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Error: No matching Packages to list
Gracias!

Comment: que so y version estas utilizando dice que requieres update!

Comment: Estoy utilizando una instancia de amazon LINUX 2

Comment: toma aquie te dicen como hacerlo [zip amzon linux2](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=270790&tstart=0)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, hice lo que dice ahi pero sigue sin funcionar:    sudo amazon-linux-extras install php7.2
sudo yum install php-pear php-devel gcc libzip-devel zlib-devel
sudo pecl install zip-1.13.5 # we must specify a slightly older version due due to compatibility

Comment: Luego reinicie con: sudo service httpd restart

Comment: debes activarlo en php.ini!

Comment: En php.ini agregue esto: extension=zip.so justo antes de donde dice ; End: